# How to install python packages using pip on go daddy linux hosting (don't have root access)

Tags: python, linux, pip

Could you tell me how to install packages using pip on Go daddy Linux hosted server. It doesn't provide root access.
When I try to install some python package

```
pip install numpy
```

it shows:

```
-bash: pip: command not found
```

It is giving my Python 2.6.6 and the location is:

```
/usr/bin/python
```

Is there any hack for it?

Comment: You don't have `pip` installed

Comment: Sorry. But I don't know how to check it. I would like to correct one thing. Python and its site-packages are in "lib/python2.6/site-packages"

Comment: I copied pip folder from my local computer to this site-packages folder. Still it didn't work

Comment: try virtualenv if available in python module or manage to install python setup tools

Comment: How to install pip in go daddy? I think I may not be able to install any package because of the restriction of root

Comment: @Grahan I tried with the same. But virtualenv is not available. My plan was to first pip install virtualenv then pip install django for uploading my site on go daddy

Comment: I read that virtualenv is available already on go daddy. as like numpy and other basic packages are already available on it but virtualenv was not there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have pip installed. To install pip run this

`easy_install --user pip`

This will install pip for only you, without root access. If you don't have 'easy_installed' installed, you can run this to install pip without it

`wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py && python get-pip.py --user`

pip will be installed in `.local/bin`, to access it just use 
`.local/bin/pip install numpy`

To add pip to your PATH, so that you could access it like `pip install numpy`

execute this command:

`echo "PATH=\$PATH:~/.local/bin" >> ~/.bashrc`

and then this:

`source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: Or you could also do `echo alias pip=./local/bin/pip >> ~/.bashrc` and then `source ~/.bashrc` and to install anything after just do `pip install xxx`

Comment: Hey, pip has been installed but it is giving this error: DEPRECATION: Python 2.6 is no longer supported by the Python core team, please upgrade your Python. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.6
Cannot uninstall requirement django, not installed

Comment: @Prasad follow this: http://thelazylog.com/install-python-as-local-user-on-linux/

Comment: I have installed few packages. thank you very much. but not able to install django which is the main reason behind installing pip

Comment: When i try to pip install django it gives the following error

Comment: OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.11.3.dist-info'

Comment: use pip install --install-dir=$HOME/.local/ django or --prefix=$HOME/.local/ if that doesn't work